# How do I display certain parts of JSON array response from Alamofire request

Tags: json, swift, api, alamofire

How do I access the JSON array to display the output of "AdjustedScheduleTime" from the Trip section?

I got it working for StopLabel as shown below, but I'm struggling to access AdjustedScheduleTime.

I tried the following:

["GetNextTripsForStopResponse"]["GetNextTripsForStopResult"]["Route"]["RouteDirection"]["Trips"]["Trip"]["AdjustedScheduleTime"]

but doesn't work.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let parameters = [
        "appID": "5rt5rydg",                 //incorrect appID
        "apiKey": "3b5fb15rdgy5454hdrfhr",  //incorrect apiKey
        "routeNo": "14",
        "stopNo": "8600",
        "format": "JSON"
    ]
    AF.request("https://api.octranspo1.com/v1.2/GetNextTripsForStop?", method: .post, parameters: parameters,encoding:
        URLEncoding.httpBody, headers: nil).responseJSON{ response in

            let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(response.result.value!)
            print(swiftyJsonVar)


            if let busInfo = swiftyJsonVar["GetNextTripsForStopResult"]["StopLabel"].string {

                print(": ",busInfo)


                print("Label1: ", self.label1.text = busInfo)
            }






            }


        }
```

This is the results:

```
{
  "GetNextTripsForStopResult" : {
    "Error" : "",
    "Route" : {
      "RouteDirection" : {
        "RouteLabel" : "St-Laurent",
        "Error" : "",
        "RequestProcessingTime" : "20190112151425",
        "Trips" : {
          "Trip" : [
            {
              "AdjustmentAge" : "0.38",
              "GPSSpeed" : "0.5",
              "Latitude" : "45.429457",
              "Longitude" : "-75.684117",
              "TripDestination" : "St-Laurent",
              "LastTripOfSchedule" : false,
              "TripStartTime" : "14:31",
              "BusType" : "4LB - IN",
              "AdjustedScheduleTime" : "11"
            },
            {
              "AdjustmentAge" : "4.32",
              "GPSSpeed" : "0.5",
              "Latitude" : "45.413749",
              "Longitude" : "-75.689748",
              "TripDestination" : "St-Laurent",
              "LastTripOfSchedule" : false,
              "TripStartTime" : "14:46",
              "BusType" : "4LB - IN",
              "AdjustedScheduleTime" : "22"
            },
            {
              "AdjustmentAge" : "0.55",
              "GPSSpeed" : "31.3",
              "Latitude" : "45.399587",
              "Longitude" : "-75.727631",
              "TripDestination" : "St-Laurent",
              "LastTripOfSchedule" : false,
              "TripStartTime" : "15:01",
              "BusType" : "4L - IN",
              "AdjustedScheduleTime" : "37"
            }
          ]
        },
        "RouteNo" : 14,
        "Direction" : "Eastbound"
      }
    },
    "StopLabel" : "MCARTHUR \/ IRWIN MILLER",
    "StopNo" : "8600"
  }
}
```

:  MCARTHUR / IRWIN MILLER          //This is the desired output for StopLabel

Comment: Can you please format your code to make it easier for us to read?

Comment: The value for key `Trip` is an array containing 3 items (note the `[]`) so there are three `AdjustedScheduleTime` values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so do you explain JSON.  Here's a shot.

### First some rules:

- When you see opening `{` it means dictionary, you have to pick a key next
- When you see opening `[` it means array. you have to pick an index
- When you see `"SomeString":` its a key in an array.
- Dictionaries have keys, arrays have index.  Pick accordingly..

### So when we walk through this response:

1. We see that we start with `{`.  We have a dictionary! We're expecting to see some keys next.
2. So lets pick a key: We only have one and it's `"GetNextTripsForStopResult"`. so far we have: `swiftyJsonVar["GetNextTripsForStopResult"]`
3. We now look at the content of "GetNextTripsForStopResult". We see it's also a dictionary. Again we should have some keys. We do.  We have `Error`, `Route`, `StopLabel` and more. Let's pick a key. Since we're trying to get to a "AdjustedScheduleTime", lets pick `Route`. so far we have `["GetNextTripsForStopResult"]["Route"]`
4. Now lets look at the contents of `Route`. Its a dictionary again.
5. Again we pick a key and keep repeating till we hit `Trip`. You should have `["GetNextTripsForStopResult"]["Route"]["RouteDirection"]["Trips"]["Trip"]`
6. Lets look at what we have in `Trip` Whats this?..its an array!
7. We have to pick an index now. We need to chose somehow. Thats the tricky part. In order to do that we need some more information.  So lets just ARBITRARILY chose one. Lets take the last one. so we have: `["GetNextTripsForStopResult"]["Route"]["RouteDirection"]["Trips"]["Trip"][2]`
8. Now we can get our final key `AdjustedScheduleTime`. So let's pick it!
   `["GetNextTripsForStopResult"]["Route"]["RouteDirection"]["Trips"]["Trip"][2]["AdjustedScheduleTime"]`

### Keep in mind:

These hard coded indexes are almost *NEVER* what you want. Maybe you need to show all the `AdjustedScheduleTime` to the user or let the user chose one, or add all of them up. That really depends on your application and what you're trying to accomplish. I chose the last index (2) arbitrarily without having any knowledge of your application, the api you're calling and what you're trying to achieve. Its VERY possible that you don't want the last index.